# Android execute shell in context of previous command from app

Tags: android, shell, android-context, execute

I know how to execute command in shell from android app

```
shell.exec("ls /");
```

and how to read response from it

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_process.getInputStream())).readLine();
```

But I have a shell app that requires extra user input after running it. And I would like to know how to send a extra input to the same shell command.

For example:

```
cp /abc/ /a/abc/
```

And lets say the command requires user to confirm overwrite by inputing extra `Y`, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to send multiple commands through shell.This works through JSCH client for ssh

```
 Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
            OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

             channel.connect();
             ps.println("mkdir folder"); 
             ps.println("dir");
     //give commands to be executed inside println.and can have any no of commands sent.
                          ps.close();

             InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
             byte[] bt=new byte[1024];


             while(true)
             {

             while(in.available()>0)
             {
             int i=in.read(bt, 0, 1024);
             if(i<0)
              break;
                String str=new String(bt, 0, i);
              //displays the output of the command executed.
                System.out.print(str);


             }
             if(channel.isClosed())
             {

                 break;
            }
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             channel.disconnect();
             session.disconnect();   
             }
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for replay, but thous commands are sent one by one instantly. But what I want is to send command, like `cp` and then read the output, and once the output contains `Do you want to rewrite file` I send response `Y`, is that possible, I'm able to read and analyze the response, but I'm not able to send response so that it understands it in context of question give, if I use `shell.exec("Y");` it gives error. (I know you can use flag to overwrite all but I have to ask user each time).

Comment: I think what you asking is not possible,because these functions were made to work only for the commands and not for user inputs.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is possible to run terminal shell hidden in background, and send input as if user typed it in real shell, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```